# degree of freedom in t.test

Tags: r

What is the difference between calculating the degree of freedom in the  formula `(n-1)` and the degree of freedom that is performed in `t.test`?

For example:
I have two group `1.(1.7,1,1)` and `2.(1.5,1,1)`

```
df = 4 (n-1)
-----------------
df in t.test = 2.9186
t = -9.1357, df = 2.9186, p-value = 0.003092
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.611410 -3.154978
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 1.236430  6.119624
```

Why are they different?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the assumption whether the variance is equal or not

```
t.test(v1, v2, var.equal = TRUE)
 Two Sample t-test

data:  v1 and v2
t = 0.2325, df = 4, p-value = 0.8276
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.7294628  0.8627961
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 1.233333  1.166667
```

By default, it is using `var.equal = FALSE`

```
t.test(v1, v2)
 Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  v1 and v2
t = 0.2325, df = 3.6193, p-value = 0.8287
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.7636018  0.8969351
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 1.233333  1.166667
```

and that uses the 'Welch' adjustment to calculate the number of degrees of freedom

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1.7, 1, 1)
v2 <- c(1.5, 1, 1)
```